# how to get a tree-structure from a self-referenced (hierarchical) table using parent ID in directus API

Tags: directus

I have parent ID in my table and I need tree structure JSON like parent and child category in directus.
I have setup the mane to one relation in parent id column in directus collection

Answer (score 0):

Using the `fields` parameter, you can fetch relational data using dot-notation.

**Examples**

- Get all top-level fields: `?fields=*`
- Get all top-level fields and all second-level relational fields:
  `?fields=*.*`
- Get all top-level fields and second-level relational fields within images: `?fields=*,images.*`

**More Documentation**

More information such as performance of wildcard details is available on the Directus Documentation.

Ref: https://docs.directus.io/reference/api/query/#fields